# How to describe algorithm in C

Tags: image-processing

I'm learning Image processing. My problem is Segmentation in RGB vector space. How to describe the Euclidean distance(Fomula 6.7-1 chap6 in Image processing- Gonzalez) to segment RGB in C programming. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand your question. are you asking how to implement a mathematical formula? because this wouldn't make sense as you learn this within 15 minutes of any C tutorial. so what is it you want to know?

Comment: Sorry for my English. I have an RGB image MxN pixels, my problem is using Euclide distance to segment this image, don't use OpenCV library (6.7.2 in the book image processing by Rafael C. Gonzalez). I don't know how to do it in C programming. So, i need a solution in C programming for it (better in C#). The final result below from my teacher.
Result: https://imgur.com/J3A7Lf6
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Minimum requirements to solve this problem:

1) learn C (to at least an medium-advanced level)

presuming that you're not going to decode jpegs or whatever image format you have from scratch:

2) learn how to use libraries in C.

3) find a library that allows you to read and write the image file format at hand

4) implement the algorithm and apply it to the image data